# numpy.float32' object does not support item assignment

Tags: numpy, hdf5

I'd like to convert data into hdf5 files, just following someone's codes. But it will report `numpy.float32 does not support item assignment` when run `row[j] = float(fields[j])`.  Is there something wrong with  `create_dataset` ?

```
import h5py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import math
import sys 

def add_lines(dset, lines):
        num_lines = len(lines)
        if num_lines == 0:
                return
        numrows = dset.shape[0]
        dset.resize(((numrows+num_lines),))
        rows = dset[numrows:(numrows+num_lines)]

        for i in range(num_lines):
                line = lines[i]
                row = rows[i]

                fields = line.split(",")
                for j in range(0,len(fields)):
                        row[j] = float(fields[j])

        dset[numrows:(numrows+num_lines)] = rows

if '__main__' == __name__:
        print 'Loading...'  
        day = sys.argv[1]
        file = day+".xls"
        batch_size = 100000
        lines = []

        f = h5py.File("out", 'a')
        if "dset" not in f:
                dset = f.create_dataset("dset", (0,), dtype="float", maxshape=(None,))
        else:
                dset = f['dset']


        with open(file, "r") as g:
                for line in g:
                        line = line.strip()
                        lines.append(line)
                        if len(lines) == batch_size:
                                add_lines(dset, lines)
                                lines = []
        add_lines(dset, lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
            for j in range(0,len(fields)):
                    row[j] = float(fields[j])
```

to

```
            row[:] = [float(v) for v in fields]
```

Except, it looks like `dset` is a 1 dimensional array, not 2d.

You may need to change the intialization of `dset` before trying to assign values row by row from the input lines.